# Wear notification duplication

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os

We have companion app and as well as wear app. My companion app will receive push notification, but I don't want to show the same notification on the wear. So I am sending the push notification payloadd to wear via data layer API and there am creating notification long with the action (to open wear app).

But this cause the duplication issue, though user has cleared the notification in mobile app but same notification exist on wear. We have tried with same notification id in both wear and mobile but it doesn't work.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question.

If the problem you have is that 2 notifications appear, then you should use [`setLocalOnly(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setLocalOnly(boolean)) to prevent the original notification from being bridged over.

If the problem is that the notification on Wear doesn't get cleared when the user clears the one on mobile, then you must setup a feedback channel using [`setDeleteIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setDeleteIntent(android.app.PendingIntent)) on both sides and coordinate clearing the notification. If you're bridging notification manually, you have to handle their cancellation as well, as this is not done automatically.

Comment: I have already using setLocalOnly(true) on mobile notification. Is there any way to clear notification by using same notification id on both wear and mobile?

Comment: No, you need to set a feedback loop between both devices using `deleteIntent`. It won't synchronize it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can add wearable only features to notifications. Check here: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html

Comment: Yes we can add wearable only features to notifications. But in action intent I need to use wear app activity(not mobile) from mobile app. So it is not possible to add action Intent.